# Disable QWidget's mask during painting or letting mouse events pass without mask

Tags: c++, qt, mask, qwidget

I have a widget that is used to *cover* other widgets. Its goal is to block mouse events on all widgets of window but a counted ones (the *uncovered* widgets). The covering widget paints a semi-translucent image everywhere but over the uncovered widgets.

I succeeded in doing it by using `QWidget::setMask` and a composition of `QRegion`s made from widget's rects (like `ALL.rect - uncovered_widget_1.rect - unconvered_widget_2.rect - ...`).

```
// mask_path is a member of type QPainterPath
// cover_widget is a member of type QWidget*
if (cover_widget->mask().isEmpty()) { // first time
  cover_widget->setMask(cover_widget->parentWidget()->rect());
  mask_path = {};
}

QPainterPath path;
path.addRect(uncovered_widget_rect);
mask_path.addPath(path);
cover_widget->setMask(cover_widget->mask().subtracted(path.toFillPolygon().toPolygon()));
```

[image]

Now, the specifications have changed a bit and now the holes shall have rounded corners. At a first attempt I changed the `addRect` with `addRoundedRect` but masks are binary and the corners do not always render *rounded* without anti-aliasing:

[image]

I can get the visual result I want by disabling the mask and using a clipping path in the paint event handler, but then the mouse events are not going through the widget.

```
QPainterPath path;
path.addRect(geometry());
painter.setClipPath(path.subtracted(mask_path));
```

[image]

I've unsuccessfully tried to ignore mouse events in the covering widget. AFAIK once an event is ignored it goes up to the parent but doesn't goes down back again to a different child (correct me if I'm wrong please).

I've seen the [`RenderFlag::IgnoreMask`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#RenderFlag-enum) but the only place to use it is through a custom call to `QWidget::render`, not during standard paint flow.

Is there any way I can get such effect: smooth clipping polygons + letting mouse events to go through only in certain areas?

Comment: If I remember right a mouse event has to be accepted. If it is not [accepted](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qevent.html#accept) it should be passed the widget hierarchy up. That's just what came in my mind spontaneously and I found worth to be mentioned... (I mean you could check the mouse position for a certain event against any geometry (or pixel) of your cover widget and decide whether to accept it or not, couldn't you?)

Comment: What I'm not sure about (and this may break my suggestion): If a mouse event is propagated to parent, I'm really not sure whether this may then be passed to other children of this parent as well... That might be checked in a [mcve] or by looking into the source code on `woboq.org`. I believe the former is easier to achieve. ;-)

Comment: An alternative might be to try [Event Filters](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/eventsandfilters.html#event-filters) instead.